# How paint line on the bottom of drawable?

Tags: android, android-drawable

I create drawable with 2 lines White and Red. But it paint on the center of drawable. I want paint it on the bottom.

My drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <stroke
                android:width="1.25dp"
                android:color="#ff0000"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <stroke
                android:width="1.25dp"
                android:color="#ffffff"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you exactly want but i think this should solve you problem

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:bottom="2dp"
        android:left="-10dp"
        android:right="-10dp"
        android:top="-10dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"></solid>
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#fff" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:left="-10dp"
        android:right="-10dp"
        android:top="-10dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"></solid>
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#f00" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```